# Entering subsets of variables in Stata commands

Tags: stata

I would like to enter groups of variables into a Stata command, but can't find a way to do so.

E.g. In a factor analysis, with a set of 41 variables, I would like to exclude the 5th, 33rd and 35th, but include the rest.

Should it be something like: `factor x1-x4, x6-x32, x34, x36-41, factors(5) pcf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example calls up a factor analysis. Let''s keep with that. If your variables are indeed at least those named out of `x1` through `x41` then

```
 factor x1-x4 x6-x32 x34 x36-x41
```

could be legal. Note that (1) the commas are **not** included; (2) the last *varlist* was corrected, as `x36-41` could never be a legal *varlist* (as `41` could never be a legal *varname*); and (3) when two or more variable names are joined with a hyphen, here `x6-x32` and `x36-x41`, such a *varlist* indicates a block of variables in the current dataset order, not necessarily all variables whose names begin with `x` with implied suffixes, e.g. in 36(1)41. Thus `x36-x41` could mean `x36 frog toad x41` if you have variables with those names in that order.

The moral is simple: have your variables in an order that makes management and analysis simple and easy to think about. The `order` command provides  the easiest way to change variable order programmatically.

The more general problem of removing variable *j* in order from an arbitrary *varlist* seems a little artificial, but here we go. Suppose we have a list of variable names (in fact any names) in a local macro. `tokenize` maps them one by one to local macros numbered `1` up, after which we can remove whatever we like. In the example below the output of `mac li` is edited to remove stuff irrelevant to this example, which could be quite a lot.

```
. local varlist foo bar bazz frog toad newt whatever

. tokenize `varlist'

. mac li
_7:             whatever
_6:             newt
_5:             toad
_4:             frog
_3:             bazz
_2:             bar
_1:             foo
_varlist:       foo bar bazz frog toad newt whatever

. foreach j in 1 3 5 {
  2. local varlist : list varlist - `j'
  }

. mac li
_varlist:       bar frog newt whatever
_7:             whatever
_6:             newt
_5:             toad
_4:             frog
_3:             bazz
_2:             bar
_1:             foo
```

For other methods of manipulating lists, see `help macrolists`.